# how to calculate fold change when we have replicate

Tags: statistical-significance, computational-statistics, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have obtained genes with ratios. As an small example you can see my data below

```
Gene    Control1     Control2   Control3    Treated1    Treated2    Treated3
pps-1   324680000   211350000   356350000   269770000   258080000   292830000
R11A8.7 477490000   610780000   539550000   533590000   530810000   578290000
ugt-21  105080000   103430000   74137000    78915000    42381000    31415000
spp-18  1042800000  615030000   332720000   538340000   448280000   412310000
```

Now My question is that I have Three controls and Three Treated, Control has two biological replicate and Treated has two biological replicate

How can I calculate the fold change for it?

I see two ways

**The first way** 
I take the average of my control group , lets call it **A** (one column)
I take the average of my treated group, lest call it **B** (one column) 
Then I calculate the fold change **(B/A)**

This way, I can check also whether the correlation between all biological replicate of control or treated are high which indicates taking the average is fine

**The second way**
I perform multi comparison test on both group 
I find up regulated genes and down regulated genes 
I discard the rest of the genes
I take the average of my control group , lets call it **A** (one column)
I take the average of my treated group, lest call it **B** (one column) 
Then I calculate the fold change **(B/A)**

which one of them make more sense?

> My main concern is how to calculate the fold change when I have
>   biological replicate ,

I posted in biology group they said it is better I post it here

> How then can one calculate p-values for fold change if it is based on
>   average

Comment: I think you mean three replicates.

Comment: @Student T yes I mean

Comment: Cross posted in [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50824/3340). @NikBernou **Do not** cross post on two sites. If you think one site is better then delete the question in the other site.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I know he cross-posted. Anyway, please review my answer. Inspired by your idea of t-test in the other post.

Answer (score 3):

2:) makes no sense to me. You would only do a t-test between control/treated if you want to test for difference in the sample means, but not for calculating the fold-change.

Fold change is typically calculated by simply `average of group 2/ average of group 1`. I'll give you a proof, in http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=49101, the author of DESeq2 wrote:

`(average in group2)/(average in group1)`

The question is **why** would you want to do this? There are good Bioconductor packages that can do that for you. For example, DESeq2 applies shrinkage methods to the fold-changes. Raw fold-change is **not** informative in bioinformatic statistical analysis, because it doesn't address the expression level (and variance) of the gene. Highly and lowly expressed genes can give you the same fold-change, and you don't want this to happen.

Comment: thank you so much. actually it has been hour and hour I was trying to explain what i want. this gives me the right path. I am more interested in doing it by myself than clicking on package looks a bit black box. is it possible to give me an explanation about for example how then they calculate p-value for this fold change? do you know?

Comment: @NikBernou I kind of know. But can you please accept the answer if it helps and then start a new question? This will show your appreciation and people will be able to help you more.

Comment: now please complete your answer, I will surely accept it

Comment: @NikBernou Please start a new question for calculating the p-value for the fold-change because this is a different topic to this question.

Comment: I accepted it , now I make a new question here

Comment: @NikBernou I think you will be better off using the highly developed, sophisticated packages like DESeq2, and devoting some effort to understanding what such "black boxes" actually do. Trying to re-invent such programs is fraught with difficulty and prone to error. You can also examine the code to see how the authors of the program deal with matters like p-values.

Comment: @EdM I agree but it is difficult to go through a package when you did not write it. most of the documentation are lacking , so understating what is what is really pain. I agree that such packages are built for those who have no programming knowledge and that si why I am trying to make something myself which I understand it fully. For example can you tell me why DESeq2 is working on count values and not continuous ? you see, it is a black box

Comment: @NikBernou there is a good deal of [useful documentation](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.pdf) for DESeq2, which is designed for the integer read counts obtained from RNAseq studies. If your data are based on microarray instead, other Bioconductor packages are available, with documentation. I also experienced the difficulty of trying to understand the workings of packages others wrote, but after overcoming the initial hurdles I learned much more than I would have trying to figure it all out on my own.

Comment: @EdM calculating fold change is not a difficult calculation. DESeq2 is meant for a specific kind of data. It is not a general statistical tool. And, it is always good to know the underlying statistics/math instead of simply clicking some buttons.